# Maven repository structure

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I don't understand how to drop jars manually to a local maven repository, and using this structure to write the project POM. here is an example, I'm trying to add a dependency "spring-dao" jar to my project

a snippet from the pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the jar is located at path/to/maven-repo/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-dao-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar

However, dependency still not recognised.

Can anybody please explain how this works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is your repository located on the default path?Like `/home/username/.m2/`?Because if not, you have to specify it in `settings.xml` like

```
<localRepository>/dev/m2repo</localRepository>
```

And then build your project with `mvn install -s path/to/settings.xml`

Btw `spring-dao` is in [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3a%22spring-dao%22) so why don't use the dependency from there?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the settings.xml, and by passing the settings.xml path to maven settings in inteliJ it automatically updated the path to maven repo with the one in between <localrepository> tag. The thing is it seems to be able to identify spring-jdbc jar but not spring-dao even though I use the same structure.

Comment: What is the error if you try to build the project from command line?And what's the exact content of `2.0.3.RELEASE` folder in your repo?